# Start and Stop a Timer with Recursive setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, settimeout

I am trying to start and stop a timer with a recursive `setTimeout`, since `setInterval` doesn't fit my need. When the user presses start, the timer starts counting.

1...2...3...4..5...1...2...3..4...5...1..2...3..4...5...

And when the user presses stop, it should stop this timer loop. If I press start again, changing the state of the button (stream variable), the timer should do the same thing again (1..2..3..4..5..1..2...3..4...5..)

I thought the way to do it would be this.

```
const ref = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  if (!stream) {
    ref.current=setTimeout(repeatingFunc, 1000);

  } else {
    clearTimeout(ref.current);
  }
}, [stream]);

function repeatingFunc() {
  console.log("It's been 5 seconds. Execute the function again.");
  setTimeout(repeatingFunc, 5000);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The timer doesn't stop. It keeps going even if I press stop! (changing the stream state value!)

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, I wrote that by memory.. but now I fixed it

Comment: You are clearing the timeout using `clearTimeout(ref.current)`, but where do you assign `ref.current`?

Comment: before, I assign it before useEffect :  const ref = useRef(null);

Comment: _"I fixed it, I wrote that by memory"_ - That's no excuse for an invalid [mcve] ;)

Comment: `clearTimeout()` expects the id of a scheduled timeout (the return value of `setTimeout`). You're not storing such an id anywhere.

Comment: I defined the id after the if condition , I clear intervakl in the else...and I declare the ref outside of useEffect.. where should I do this?

Comment: Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-worker-ijz78n) with a very simple start-stop implementation of the timer. Just as a precaution the timer will automatically stop at count 60. Probably not very helpful as an answer - but hopefully a good reference point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the timer doesn't stop is because you only store the timeout ID of the initial `setTimeout` call. When `repeatingFunc` is called another `setTimeout` callback is registered, which has a new timeout ID.

So when you try to clear the timeout using `clearTimeout(ref.current)` you are passing an outdated timeout ID.

Since the previous `setTimeout` registration is already called, you no longer need to store the previous ID and you could simply replace it with the new one.

```js
const ref = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!stream) {
    ref.current = setTimeout(repeatingFunc, 1000);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(ref.current);
  }
}, [stream]);

function repeatingFunc() {
  console.log("It's been 5 seconds. Execute the function again.");
  ref.current = setTimeout(repeatingFunc, 5000);
  // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ update timeout ID after registering a new timeout
}
```

Note that the scope of `repeatingFunc` is fixed in a point in time where you initially call `setTimeout(repeatingFunc, 1000)`, meaning that things like states and properties can contain outdated values. This might or might not become a problem depending on your context.

---

You might also want to add a `useEffect` cleanup function that clears the timeout on component dismount. Otherwise your loop keeps going, even when the component is no longer mounted.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!stream) {
    ref.current = setTimeout(repeatingFunc, 1000);
  }

  return () => clearTimeout(ref.current);
}, [stream]);
```

Assuming `stream` is a boolean (`true`/`false`) the above will clear the current timeout whenever the value of `stream` is changed, or on component dismount.

When `stream` changes from `true` to `false`, the cleanup function will be called and the timeout will be cleared.

When `stream` changes from `false` to `true` the cleanup function is also called, but results in a no-op because the current `ref.current` is no longer registered. Then a new timeout is set.

> Passing an invalid ID to `clearTimeout()` silently does nothing; no exception is thrown.

See: [MDN - `clearTimeout()`](https://%5BMDN%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout))

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom timer like this:

```
function CustomTimer(func) {
    this.id = -1;
    this.func = func;

    this.start = function (interval) {
        this.stop();

        if (this.func) {
            var t = this;
            this.id = setTimeout(function () { t.func.call(t) }, interval || 1000);
        }
    }

    this.stop =  function () {
        if (this.id >= 0) {
            clearTimeout(this.id);
            this.id = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var myTimer = new CustomTimer(function () {
    console.log("It's been 5 seconds. Execute the function again.");
    this.start(5000);
});

myTimer.start(5000);
```

You can change the function to execute in any moment and also the interval. For example: run a start event in 1 second and then, 5 times every 5 seconds do other thing:

```
var secondFunc = function () {
    console.log("It's been 5 seconds. Execute the function again.");

    if (++this.count < 5)
        this.start(5000);
}

var myTimer = new CustomTimer(function () {
    console.log("First event at 1 second");

    this.count = 0;
    this.func = secondFunc;
    this.start(5000);
});

myTimer.start(1000);
```